# In Cocos2d, with buttons on multiple layers, how can I control which button to react to user's touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

Now I have a `CCLayer` of gameplay, where there are a few buttons. And I want to pop up a dialog layer, where there are also a few buttons. How can I deactivate the background buttons and only make the foreground buttons activated?

Comment: Did you find some good solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Use CCMenuItem `setIsEnabled` method to disable button.

Comment: This question is kind of a dupe but yeah, Andrew's way is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

What about a lot of buttons on gameplay? Disable every button looks like not the best solution... Is it possible to disactivate all buttons in one fell swoop as topic starter requested?